# Can't correctly index an object using "union" index type

Tags: typescript

First of all, I'm not really sure what's wrong with my code, so if there's any better title suggestion, I will edit it, thanks.

I try to index an object using "key" which is of a union type, if the type of key is narrowed down, there's no problem, but if the type is of a union type TS is not happy about it, why?

Also I don't understand the error TS says, where does that intersection type come from?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYhwGMAWEAmARAhsTUC8UA3gFBRlQCCA-AFxGnmMU0DkFLANA42QPbAoATjACWEADao6AZ2CCRAOwDm3KAF8ujAEK16PcltZbOqxvyGiJUqLPnLVG1QGFdJfWSesnJ91HMRhMUkZOUUVRkc1AG5iYlBIKCdMZDQsHHw9cmZM-WY2FgdNAzo3d0MWY0LnEtNyTxZvKujYhF4FWSgEZJQMbEw6JJTe9IJSsmyxnjz2Ku0a33LKiKKPefd6xuXiNVj46ABpCBAMgGsj3gAzWHghtMwY4lb24CgzkDpD44IAWWwkADpBJgFKheABbAAUAEooAA+KAABn+ADYoFQoPkoHRfgJAcDQZCYfCkQBmNEY4xYjHeB5PDoXG49O50OCIJl9DKEZrEaQAdxEbKgELeMMmXWk0AARBRJVTJow6S8uikMsr2TgANpvAC6tTIDLZqT6WqO2s5-wtaogHD8AgClmCGP8gSsLB2EVUAHpPVA7VBMAAjXgAN2gImkfhOmBANoDAFcXsBoAGJLxeVBw1AFPwbbykCAqKpUBALpg4+IXmt9IrOt1oAQrcNMCaQLrfJ6AFRQPU8GtWqu+KZ0fIxQfkNRQAA+OTHxQpLFHs4n0-ls881IXPY9vg7np7Btuxp15stdZtzod1hYF6CqDdPc73dnUAAKuBoCxCLaLLeQnYlFElB0NKkqAcuRDfvav42KEyiAYYUCSlooHqFOEE3lYf5hIB66Sk4KFqCwGYRtmLyYNI0giEoCiBuI0DALwvrvhiEJftkIGARhjq2NhqEAGQQQhSEoVx1g8XB-EQbh+GcXaLrcbBAHqDC05xiCJaKGgLD-Fu5Bvgkn6QfJYmKYB7EymBRGZqR-oUVRNEBnRvqMXsGJscBFlGZeWESROAlfkJyGyT+mEwf+YFQP5iTATJXnQeJSmETpz4AAqCLwkCCKA87EVAYLhpRygZgoTEGV+ok+Up5kEUR8YvIIEAAI5xiIDWoMVpUfgFwFBXFoUJZZ-zANIEIAEwkqNo1Qj2Pa7rE7Y+gAklAoIKCwLxqcWgiyPiUB5scL4AMo2NGEaSha-xZvwtmUdRtH0S5zEsKxQGIZ5FVhbxfmCT1Ilyd5n2+ZFUAXbKeYBNAoIQBGAjYMVSbbRACDACIbSdOC0AXOlYKFh6ahAA)

```
type FetchedData = {
    A?: {
        A:'A',
        otherField: string
    },
    B?: {
        B:'B',
        otherField: string
    },
    C?: {
        C:'C',
        otherField: string
    },
};

type CachedData = {
    A: {
        A:'A'
    },
    B: {
        B:'B'
    },
    C: {
        C:'C'
    },
};

const cachedData: CachedData = {
    A: {
        A:'A'
    },
    B: {
        B:'B'
    },
    C: {
        C:'C'
    },
}

type Key = keyof FetchedData;

const key: Key = Math.random() > 0.6 ? 'A' : Math.random() > 0.3 ? 'B' : 'C';

const fetchedData: FetchedData = {};

switch (key) {
    case "A" : {
        const cache = cachedData[key]
        fetchedData[key] = {...cache, otherField: 'otherField'}
    }
    // the above is okay, but te below is not, why?
    default : {
        const cache = cachedData[key]
        /* 
            const cache: {
                A: 'A';
            } | {
                B: 'B';
            } | {
                C: 'C';
            }
        */
        fetchedData[key] = {...cache, otherField: 'otherField'}
        /* 
            Type '{ otherField: string; A: "A"; } | { otherField: string; B: "B"; } | { otherField: string; C: "C"; }' is not assignable to type '({ A: "A"; otherField: string; } & { B: "B"; otherField: string; } & { C: "C"; otherField: string; }) | undefined'.
            Type '{ otherField: string; A: "A"; }' is not assignable to type '{ A: "A"; otherField: string; } & { B: "B"; otherField: string; } & { C: "C"; otherField: string; }'.
            Property 'B' is missing in type '{ otherField: string; A: "A"; }' but required in type '{ B: "B"; otherField: string; }'.ts(2322)
        
        */

        // I don't understand why TS says "... not assignable to type '({ A: "A"; otherField: string; } & { B: "B"; otherField: string; } & ..." where does that intersection come from?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript does not really support *correlated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)*.  Since `key` is of a union type, then both `const cache = cachedData[key]` and `fetchedData[key] = {...cache, otherField: 'otherField'}` involve union types.  But the compiler just treats them independently, according to their *types* and not the identity of `key`.  Imagine instead of `key` you had `key1` and `key2`, both of the same union type as `key`.  You wouldn't want the compiler to accept `fetchedData[key1] = {...cachedData[key2], otherField: 'otherField'}`, right?  Because while `key2` and `key1` have the same union type, they might not be the same *value*.  And from the point of view of the type system alone, there's no way to distinguish that scenario from your code.  The [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) comes from the compiler saying what it would take to be sure that such an assignment would be safe no matter what `key1` and `key2` are.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) for the PR that introduced this intersection behavior and how it works.

So that's what's wrong.  Your code is probably fine but the compiler can't follow the logic.

---

If you want to just do the most expedient thing, accept that you're smarter than the compiler here and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error:

```
const cache = cachedData[key]
fetchedData[key] = { ...cache, otherField: 'otherField' } as any
```

Otherwise:

If you are going to use union types then you will need to use case-by-case analysis, like `switch`/`case` or `if`/`else` to narrow `key` to individual union members before operating on them... a single block of code won't work.  If you want to use a single block of code, then you'll need to switch away from union types to [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) which have been [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to unions.  The particular refactoring technique is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) as a way to support correlated unions.

In the example code it could look like this.  Start with your base `CachedData` type:

```
type CachedData = {
    A: { A: 'A' },
    B: { B: 'B' },
    C: { C: 'C' },
};
type Key = keyof CachedData;
const cachedData: CachedData = {
    A: { A: 'A' },
    B: { B: 'B' },
    C: { C: 'C' },
}
```

then express `FetchedData` as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `CachedData`, and make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the subset of keys you care about:

```
type FetchedData<K extends Key = Key> =
    { [P in K]?: CachedData[P] & { otherField: string } }
const fetchedData: FetchedData = {};
```

Finally we can write your single block of code as the body of a generic function over `K extends Key`:

```
function f<K extends Key>(key: K) {
    const cache = cachedData[key];
    // const cache: CachedData[K]
    const _fetchedData: FetchedData<K> = fetchedData;
    const v = { ...cache, otherField: 'otherField' };
    // const v: CachedData[K] & { otherField: string; }
    _fetchedData[key] = v;
}
```

This compiles because `cache` is of generic type `CachedData[K]`, and `_fetchedData[key]` is seen as generic type `CachedData[K] & { otherField: string }`. Neither of those are union types.  And the value `{...cache, otherField:'otherField'}` is seen as the same type `CachedData[K] & { otherField: string }` as `_fetchedData[key]`.

Finally you can call your function with a union-typed `key` as the input:

```
const key: Key =
    Math.random() > 0.6 ? 'A' : Math.random() > 0.3 ? 'B' : 'C';

f(key); // okay
```

It's quite a bit of hoop-jumping to appease the compiler here.  You have to rewrite some of your types and copy some of your values to the appropriate types.  Personally I'd probably just use a type assertion and not bother with the refactoring, unless I really had a particular need to favor compiler-verified types over expedience.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgQwMYAsoBMAiCQJgXhgG9gYyYBBALmMpoHIL6YBfAGlPICEaiYeY9Ls3acycXvAZwRHFgG5goSLADSUMARgBrDQHsAZvGRosOBIuXQYAMSghUGbLgA8qmFAAeIKADt0AM4w6pqEIQB8BGK0ANoACjAAlr7BALoA-DSIjma48akwAGS0eiBoAE42iVAANug0ASDlyQDmrKxKSHq+jTBIJk7mWQO5eIQk5HS01IJMrByTAnwCQrLRErQb9DLzwCyd3b26YDQhUZMAsjgoAHTlCP56ALYAFACUMJEADDcAbDDpWbMGhXMp3B7oZ7vT4wH4AZgBgmEMGk9EswC6PRAMAM9hyzgQNDsDlMBK0RAUByxfQGWn6+PMMWOqWAuJJgzyzPJMBuvPpaDYMFKFSqtXqgmFUEq1TqIhgCCCDzASlZAFdfEgQIluji3B5vH5AsENOEXsdTh8JuRMb1+bBCHbRkyNKlFJMAPTuvqHbF24YMvKqFmTG3YgD6bIDhNseNJ5jckUIkbjuDd1p9MAAbtzeTc7YLJdKxQxC6LZaw02RPd7qZn-SmEDEg0USmUpWXxY1mr4WvIOpMI7GOY2uYRM4p9qyzRo3iqgA)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is as usual very helpful and informative (as in other stack over threads), I'm new to TypeScript and your answers on stack overflow really help me learn a lot! (Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.)